# Why does the centroid of a triangle stay in place when one side of it is rotated?

Tags: geometry, triangles, centroid

I was experimenting with GeoGebra and I found something that I don't quite understand.

I wanted to see what would happen to the centroid of a triangle if one of its sides rotated inside a circle ($\bar{AB}$ would always be the diameter).

But when I rotated the side, the centroid stayed in place and didn't move at all.

I tried to generalize this so I could understand what was happening: I started by defining an arbitrary curve $\vec{r}(t) = r_x \vec{i} + r_y \vec{j}$ and a point $A=\vec{r}(t_A)$ on that curve.

Because I want $\bar{AB}$ to be the diameter, Point $B$ would have to be $B=-\vec{r}(t_A)$.

I constructed $\overset{\triangle}{ABC}$ with points $A$, $B$ and $C=(x_c,y_c)$, then I found the medians and the centroid of the triangle by solving for where they intersect.

Interestingly, I found that the centroid is always $G=(\frac{x_c}{3},\frac{y_c}{3})$; and because I chose an arbitrary curve for points $A$ and $B$ to move on, the centroid would always have these coordinates and will only be dependent on point $C$ no matter what the curve is. This also works in 3 dimensions.

I don't know if it's possible to upload videos on here, but seeing this in motion is really interesting so here's the Google Drive link to the GeoGebra files: [Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1uWi-KdSFSvGCRgkzkJWVpyK4JDGHoLrN?usp=sharing)

I understand why $G$ stays in place from a mathematical standpoint because I solved for it; but I don't quite get the intuition behind it and I haven't seen something like this before, why does it have to stay in place no matter what the curve is?

Also, I know this is a place for math questions and I'm sorry if this last part is off-topic, but would this have anything to do with the first animation on the Wikipedia page for the [Three-Body Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-body_problem)? The fact that the center of mass of these 3 particles remains in place seems kind of similar to this question, is this a physical thing or a geometrical thing?

Comment: I won't be downloading files from your google drive (because no no), but from what you write it seems to me that you have a triangle $\triangle ABC$ inscribed in a circle $\Gamma$ of diameter $AB$ (therefore it isn't just any triangle, but rather a triangle such that $AC\perp BC$) and you suggest that the locus of its centroid $G_C$ as $C$ ranges over $\Gamma$ should be a single point. That's not true: the locus described by $G_C$ will be the circle of the same center and radius $\frac16\overline{AB}$ (without the points that lie on $AB$).

Comment: HInt: Centroid = $ ((x_a + x_b + x_c ) / 3, (y_a + y_b + y_c ) / 3 ) $. So if $C$ is fixed, and $A+B $ is also fixed, then the centroid is fixed. $\quad$ So, apart from a circle, you could use any graph that is symmetric through the center (like $ y = 1/x$).

Comment: @CalvinLin Thank you for your help! I see that by setting $B=-\vec{r}(t_A)$ I essentially created a curve that is symmetric through the center, and so the $x$ and $y$ values of points $A$ and $B$ cancel each other out and the only point that defines the centroid is $C$.